# Thevenin Equivalent Circuit with Sinusoidal Current Source (Vth)

Tags: thevenin

In a practice test we are asked to find the Thevenin equivalent by finding the Thevenin voltage and Norton current within the following circuit.

[image]

We were given the following answer for Vth:

[image]
[image]

I feel like I'm making a simple mistake but I'm coming up with 
Vth= [image] which is equal to [image] as I see he wrote down. So why does it wind up as 7+7j?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are both correct, although you are more precise. The "7's" in the result 7 + 7j are an approximation of 5*sqrt(2) which somewhat more precisely = 7.07107, so I would prefer the solution given in rectangular form be 7.1 + 7.1j since 7.07.... rounds closer to 7.1 than 7.0

Comment: Okay thank you. Makes sense, it was just slightly confusing. Maybe I needed some extra sleep! haha

Comment: Sometimes professors will drive you nuts by insisting on perfect precision from their students, then they go ahead and use approximations without warning you. [I know I've been fooled like that back in the day.] This may be one of those cases. Anyway, glad I could help. Would you kindly give me an up-vote on the answer provided ? I am new to this board and I could use the points. Thanks !